# 2-point correlator of the isospin current

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

given the isospin current

$$J_{\mu}(x) \propto \bar{u}(x)\gamma_{\mu}u(x)-\bar{d}(x)\gamma_{\mu}d(x)\,,$$
I want to evaluate the 2-point correlator

$$\langle \bar{\psi}(x)\gamma_{\mu}\psi(x)\bar{\psi}(0)\gamma_{\mu}\psi(0)\rangle$$
for the zeroth component.

For e.g. $\mu = 1$ I get after Wick contraction

$$ \langle \bar{\psi}(x)\gamma_{1}\psi(x)\bar{\psi}(0)\gamma_{1}\psi(0)\rangle = -\langle (\gamma_1)_{\alpha\beta}\psi_{\beta}(x)\bar{\psi}(0)_{\gamma}(\gamma_1)_{\gamma\delta}\psi_{\delta}(0)\bar{\psi}(x)_{\alpha}\rangle = -Tr\{\gamma_1 G(x,0)\gamma_1G(0,x)\}\,.$$

But what about the zeroth component? There I am left with

$$ \langle\psi^{\dagger}(x)\psi(x)\psi^{\dagger}(0)\psi(0)\rangle\,.$$

But for the Wick contraction I need terms $\propto \psi\bar{\psi}$.

I would be very grateful for any help.